# "Could not resolve host: github" error while trying to push remote to github

Tags: bash, git, github, push

When I try to push my local commit to my GitHub page it gives me this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github/TimothyCottrell/OrganizationApp.git/': Could not resolve host: github
```

I believe that it has something to do with me switching accounts in the git bash. but I altogether have no idea what could be causing this. I see that a lot of people that get this error solve the problem by changing there proxy setting but I am not using any proxy.

Comment: Just look at what it says: `https://github`. That is wrong. — This is not even a programming problem, what's it doing here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `github.com` instead of `github`

```
https://github.com/TimothyCottrell/OrganizationApp.git
```